# AddWithValue contains # that needs to be " "

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a sql update statement inside my update_ckick event:

```
Dim tmp_date As Date
        Dim YearDateTime As New Nullable(Of Date)

        If Date.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, tmp_date) Then
            YearDateTime = tmp_date
        Else
            YearDateTime = Nothing
        End If
```

`Update Details set EMP_DateAppointedRank = @EMP_DateAppointedRank`

`UpdateEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMP_DateAppointedRank", String2Date(YearDateTime))`

that's just a snippet, what happens is when I step the line `Update Details set EMP_DateAppointedRank = @EMP_DateAppointedRank` value shows `#10/03/2014#`

How Can I make that value just: `10/03/2014` no #?

C# help also welcome

Comment: *Where* are you seeing the #? I strongly suspect this is just the VB debugger representation of a `DateTime`. That should be absolutely fine... you're specifying the value *as* a `DateTime`, not a string, so you shouldn't care what string representation is shown in the debugger.

Comment: The point of using parameterized queries that you do not have to worry about type conversion. Just let it do what it needs to do.

Comment: If you think that it's currently wrong, something must be making you think that, but it sounds like you've misdiagnosed the problem - so, is there an *error message*? If so, what is it? You may also need to show more of the code.

Comment: incorrect syntax at `EMP_DateAppointedRank` that is where I get the error that's why I suspected it is the `#`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are mistaking what's being displayed by the visual studio debugger with what it actually means.

`#10/03/2014#` is a [`Date` literal in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711653%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It just means that it's type is a `Date`(`DateTime` in C#) and it's value is `10/03/2014`.

Apart from that, you have to prepend `@` in the sql-parameter if you use MS-Sql-Server and the `Date` variable instead of the `String`:

```
If YearDateTime.HasValue Then
    UpdateEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_DateAppointedRank", YearDateTime.Value)
Else
     UpdateEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_DateAppointedRank", DBNull.Value)
End If
```